# Three.js: Object3D added in scene, attached to another object3D doesn't update position on translation

Tags: three.js

The logic of my code is such as the `object3D` which are included in the scene, on double click get added with a `Line` (with `BufferGeometry`). 
I am getting the `object3D` by using `Raycaster` intersect.
The way I am adding it is:

```
scene.add( newLine );
newLine.updateMatrixWorld();
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( newLine, scene, intersects[0].object );
```

The following is my `mousemove` code which helps me moving the `object3D` in XZ plane.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    var mouseX = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    var mouseY = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2( mouseX, mouseY );
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera);  
    if (selection) {
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );
        selection.position.copy( intersects[0].point.sub( offset ));
    }
}
```

Nothing complicated. Simple code. And the movement is happening well. I can easily move the `object3D` around.

When I am checking the console for change in position of `object3D` on grabbing and moving it, it is changing which is what should happen. But I do not see any change at in the position of the `Line`, i.e., `newLine` as in my code. The issue is unless I am calling `.updateWorldMatrix()` as well which as per THREE docs, should automatically be called in each render cycle. Still I am calling that. Why am not able to get the position of my `newLine` when clearly its position is moving along with the `object3D` when I am dragging `object3D` around?

Why is it needed? Unless the position of the line can show as changing, I can't update an HTML element, which I am attaching to the end of that line. Hence, the position change is imperative. Gif attached which shows, when the cube/ sphere/ cone is moved, `render(..)` gives me changing position log of that. However, when logging the same for the `Line` it doesn't change. If any can help me with the issue, it will be amazing. Thanks much.

[image]

**EDIT**

When I am attaching the `HTMLElement` directly to parent `object3D` it shows expected result. It moves when I move `object3D`. This is because as said its `position` is being updated continuously in the render cycle when I move it.

Gif:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line's `.position` attribute is not changing because its local position remains the same. Since the line is attached to the parent, its relative position to the parent doesn't change, only the global position does. To get the global position of `line`, you can use the `.getWorldPosition()` method:

```js
// Declare var to store world position
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();

// Get world position of line
line.getWorldPosition(worldPos);

// Now global position is stored in Vec3
console.log(worldPos);
```

Comment: Ok, let me try and get back. Thanks.

Comment: Man, I should have thought of it, tch! :)